# List currently running apps on android using cordova/phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am developing a phonegap/cordova android app that will run in background and needs to check if some app "X" was launched by the user or not .

To do this check , I am hoping to be able to retrieve a list of all the currently running apps on the device that moment .

I am not a native android programmer and looking for a way to deal with the problem using cordova/phonegap .

The ultimate aim is to be able to check from my phonegap/cordova app is , whether some app com.X is running or not .

Comment: I don't think it exists yet. You will need to build a custom plugin of your own.